# Sorting arrays inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort some arrays inside an array.

For example:

```
let mainArr = [['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
```

In this case I want to sort it by person's age, so the output would be:

```
let mainArrSorted = [['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
```

Any sugestions?

**NOTE: I don't want to implement array.sort() method.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like you are sorting by the age(assuming that is what number is in each sub array) of each array. you could sort by [i][1] ?

Comment: you could sort it as you would sort an array with single items.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You would sort it like you would sort an array of any objects, by their `[1]` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array sort function:

```js
let mainArr = [['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
let mainArrSorted = mainArr.sort((a,b)=>(a[1]-b[1]));
console.log(mainArrSorted);
// mainArrSorted = [['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
```

To prevent the source array will be sorted follow the destination array, you can use this code:

```js
let mainArr = [['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
let mainArrSorted = mainArr.slice();
mainArrSorted.sort((a,b)=>(a[1]-b[1]));
console.log(mainArrSorted); 
// mainArrSorted = [['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
```

Or if you don't want array sort, you can use this code:

```js
let mainArr = [['john', 27, 'teacher'], ['Mary', 17, 'student'], ['Jane', 40, 'police']];
let mainArrSorted = mainArr.slice();
for(let i=0;i<mainArrSorted.length-1;i++){
    for(let j=i+1;j<mainArrSorted.length;j++){
        if(mainArrSorted[i][1]>mainArrSorted[j][1]){
            let temp = mainArrSorted[i];
            mainArrSorted[i] = mainArrSorted[j];
            mainArrSorted[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
console.log(mainArrSorted);
```

Comment: you do realise you've also sorted mainArr - which may not be what is required

Comment: You should use the builtin-functions (sort), it will quicker than the another function that you made!